# Python replace every 3rd value with previous 2 items sum when not equal

Tags: list, replace

A given list is n=[3,1,5,9,6,14] , replace 5 with 3+1 and 14 with 9+6. The output will look like [3,1,4,9,6,15]

My approach was using a range and assign value
i+ [i+1]==[i+2]

I tried 2 ways but in both cases I am getting out of bound exception

```
#Approach 1
for idx,item in enumerate(n):
  if (idx + (idx+1))!=(idx+2):
      n[idx+2]=(idx + (idx+1))


#Approach2
for i in range(len(n)):
    if n[i]+n[i+1]!=n[i+2]:
        n[i + 2]==n[i]+n[i+1]
print(n)
```

Even doing a len(n)-1 does not solve the problem. Some directions will be helpful. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the mod (`%`) operator to check for every third item:

```
items = [3, 1, 5, 9, 6, 14]

for i, item in enumerate(items):
    if ((i+1) % 3 == 0):
        items[i] = items[i-1] + items[i-2]

print(items)
```

Or to be more efficient, use `range` as mentioned in the comments:

```
for i in range(2, len(items), 3):
    items[i] = items[i-1] + items[i-2]

print(items)
```

Comment: Thanks, if I understand correctly you are saying if current index+ next index modulus 3 ==0 then do the update. Here 3 is not item or index.

Comment: You're not using `item`, so you don't need the `enumerate` here. `for i in range(2, len(items), 3)` (using a step to get every third value) would be better, and allow you to skip the modulo.

Comment: @muru, you're correct! I made the change as suggested.

Comment: @SheikhRahman yes, you can either use modulus to skip to find every third index or more efficiently use the range which allows you to build a sequence and shortcut the looping a bit.